# Rspec: why is my post :create throwing a :new route not found error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

In a little Rspec test like this:

```
describe 'POST create' do
  context 'with valid attributes' do
    @document = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:document_with_publication)
    it 'creates a new document' do
      sign_in admin
      post :create, document: @document
      expect(response).to change(Document, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
end
```

I get this error:

```
DocumentsController user is an administrator POST create with valid attributes creates a new document
 Failure/Error: post :create, document: @document
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:controller=>"documents", :action=>"new", :template=>nil}
```

Why do I seem to be hitting my `:new` action and not `:create`? My routes look like this:

```
resources :documents, except: [:new, :show]
get 'documents/:template/new', to: 'documents#new', as: :new_templated_document
```

Thanks. Relevant controller code is here:

```
def new
  @document = current_user.documents.new
  @document.template = Template.find(params[:template])
  @template_resources = TemplateResources.new(@document, current_user)
end

def create
  @document = current_user.documents.new(params[:document])
  if @document.save
    second_stage_processing
  else
    redirect_to new_templated_document_path(@document.template), flash:
    { error: 'The document you tried to create was invalid: ' \
             "#{@document.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| msg }.join}" }
  end
end
```

Comment: you should post your controller code

Comment: Ah, sorry, added now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is hitting the create action and the `@document.save` is failing which causes the redirect to `redirect_to new_templated_document_path(@document.template)` to be called.  Since :template is required for that route, but is nil, the route is failing.

Comment: Makes sense. How can I diagnose that though? Especially if it creates itself in other parts of the test just fine?

Comment: You should be able to tell from the full backtrace exactly what line the error occurs on.  Either put `--backtrace` in your .rspec file or run rspec with the `-b` option to get full backtraces.  You could also try commenting out the redirect to see if the error changes/goes away.

Comment: Thanks for your help, you were right about the original question so I've marked your answer as accepted. I just need to figure out the next part of the problem now.